# Determine for which $x,\alpha,\beta$ holds $\frac{x^\alpha}{(x^\alpha+(1-x)^\alpha)^{1/\alpha}}>\frac{x^\beta}{(x^\beta+(1-x)^\beta)^{1/\beta}}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let us take into consideration the following inequality: 
$$\frac{x^\alpha}{(x^\alpha+(1-x)^\alpha)^\frac{1}{\alpha}}>\frac{x^\beta}{(x^\beta+(1-x)^\beta)^\frac{1}{\beta}}$$
where $x,\alpha,\beta\in[0,1]$. Is it possible to solve the inequality for $x$? Alternatively, how determine for which $x,\alpha,\beta$ the inequality is satisfied? Any guidance is highly appreciated!

Comment: So you could define a function
$$
f_{\eta}(x) = \frac{x^{\eta}}{\left(x^{\eta}+(1-x)^{\eta} \right)^{1/\eta}}
$$
And perhaps graph the function for different values of $\eta$ ... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cp6x83x8vq

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks for comment. I need to solve the inequality for $x$, i.e. modeify inequality so that $x>f(\alpha; \beta)$, where $f$ is a function from $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Matti P. hint does give you answer to your original question. First consider the case $\alpha > \beta$, which $x$ satisfy your inequality? Then consider the case $\alpha < \beta$.

Comment: @quarague Okay, but how determine for which $x$ is satisfied the inequality if $\alpha>\beta$?

Answer (score 0):

*Only considerations using plots, no proof.*

$\displaystyle f_z(x):=\frac{x^z}{(x^z+(1-x)^z)^{1/z}}$

$\alpha<\beta~$ :

If $~f_\alpha(x)=f_\beta(x)~$ then $~x=x_0~~$ (only one ? common point):

$(a) ~~~~ x<x_0~~ => ~~f_\alpha(x)>f_\beta(x)$

$(b) ~~~~ x>x_0~~ => ~~f_\alpha(x)<f_\beta(x)$

And $~f_\alpha(x)\ne f_\beta(x)~~$ (no common point): $~$ Not possible ?

$\alpha>\beta~$ : we exchange $\alpha$ and $\beta$ above

To get $~f_\alpha(x)>f_\beta(x)~$ we need to discuss 
the cases $~(a)~$ if $~\alpha<\beta~$ and $~(b)~$ if $~\alpha>\beta~$ .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How determine $x_0$?

Comment: It's not necessary to evaluate $x_0$ explicit but it's necessary to proof, that there is exactly one solution $x_0$ . Then the discussion of the behaviour of $f_z(x)$ should give the answer to your question.

Comment: Could you please give a bit more explanation to your answer. I guess I don't understand it properly. Thanks!

Comment: @sane: It's not an answer, only some considerations based on plots. You can do the same, e.g. compare $f_{0.1}(x), f_{0.5}(x), f_{0.9}(x)$ with $0<x<1$ . Then you can consider why the intersection point $ x_0 $ (depending on $\alpha$ and $\beta$) exists for each $f_\alpha(x)=f_\beta(x)$ with $\alpha\neq\beta$ .

Comment: Okay, I see, thanks!